# Adding search box on map with google api android

Tags: android, google-maps, direction, waze

I already add the search box and everything works well on every device with google maps installed, but when I try in a device with no google maps installed on it, the function doesn't work. I'm confused and try to add a waze deep links just in case if the device doesn't have google maps app so it might have waze. But waze deep link only works to direct to waze app. Any ideas or solution? I'm kinda confused cause not all Android device install google maps

Answer (score 1):

hey Iganov you are right not all Android device install google maps. So you can check if the device is installed the maps application then only enable your search filed to work.
so you can create function to check as below

```
boolean GoogleMaps(String apk) {
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 try {
   pm.getPackageInfo(apk, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

     return false;
   }
```

then you can call it in your on create activity as below

```
boolean appavialble = GoogleMaps("com.check.application");  

if(appavialble ) {
 //do your searching condition here         

 } else {
  //application not found force to download it or show alert 

  Uri.Builder uriBuilder = null;
 try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     uriBuilder = 
     Uri.parse("market://details").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("id", 
      "com.check.application");
      intent.setData(uriBuilder.build());
         startActivity(intent);

      }catch (Exception e){

       system.out.println("error in connection");
    }


 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if the user doesnt have  google maps on their device . the are not able to use search feature? Is there any way i can do so all user can use search box. But thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @Iganov May be we can. you can use another functionality such as [ Place Api ](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) which does not uses maps but just displaces places result into the list view.